# Laravel - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::run()

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

it's me again,

I'm still new in this Laravel world, I've overcome many issues but this one is driving me crazy. The error state the following:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::run()

I don't know where else to look. I found similar issues with the `bindShared()` and `share()` functions but not with the `run()`.

I'm guessing it's a "core" function since it's the responsible for deploying the whole application.

I checked the following things:

- htaccess (modified in order to find the project folder)
- Apache configuration
- PHP Extensions (I guess all of them are enabled otherwise the project would give me the "Whoops" error or a 500 error
- Laravel\Collective for HTML forms (I'm using that one since the previous core package was deprecated)

Here is my `htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    #RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/itccomercioexterior-system
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /itccomercioexterior-system/$1 [L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 

</IfModule>
```

here is my `index.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

try {
    $app->run();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $e;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

And finally my tree view:

```
/project
├── css
│   ├── app.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── font-awesome.css
│   └── gridcss.css
├── favicon.ico
├── fonts
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff
│   └── fontawesome-webfont.woff2
├── index.php
├── js
│   ├── app.js
│   └── index.js
├── laravel
│   ├── app
│   ├── artisan
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── composer
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── composer.lock
│   ├── config
│   ├── database
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── phpunit.xml
│   ├── readme.md
│   ├── resources
│   ├── routes
│   ├── server.php
│   ├── storage
│   ├── tests
│   ├── vendor
│   └── webpack.mix.js
├── media
│   ├── aduanas.jpg
│   ├── aduanas.png
│   ├── carousel001.jpg
│   ├── carousel002.jpg
│   ├── carousel003.png
│   ├── carousel004.jpg
│   ├── contacto.jpg
│   ├── curso1.jpg
│   ├── curso2.jpg
│   ├── curso3.jpg
│   ├── cursos.jpg
│   └── logo.webp
├── mix-manifest.json
├── robots.txt
├── storage
│   └── logs
└── web.config
```

Any insight will be appreciated!

Thank you all again!

Comment: Your first mistake was to not follow the correct laravel directory structure. I'm afraid you're on your own.

Comment: And what is the correct structure?. I read on how to upload to a shared hosting and a vps and the majority agreed on: or moving the public's folder content to the root (public_html) or just redirect apache to the public content. Either way, you have to change the paths in the index.php so it can build the application.

Comment: In laravel version 5+ (which does not actually have an `$app->run()` function by the way) what you have in the laravel folder needs to go up one level and everything else needs to go under a `public` folder. That public folder needs to be the host document root. You can possibly move the contents of public to `public_html` and then symlink public_html to public but if you have your source under your host root then it's very likely to be available for the world to see

Comment: Oh, shame on me. In fact I have that noted down :facepalm:. You are correct on that structure. I'll correct it for the sake of _security 101_. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: [it doesn't exists a `run` method in the in the `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` class](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.html).

Where did this came from? It doesn't look like the `index.php` that comes with Laravel.

```
try {
    $app->run();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $e;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Have you try deleting it?

Comment: I just did composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` and no try/catch by default in the index.php. I'll try deleting that and get back here with the results. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that was it. I think I know where that came from. On my branch I don't have that piece of code, but on my friend's branch is just there. Geez.